# configure error on FreeBSD

Tags: common-lisp, ecl

I git clone the newest ECL and do the following:

```
$./configure --prefix=/home/***/ecl
...
configure: error: Oops, mp_limb_t is 32 bits, but the assembler code
in this configuration expects 64 bits.
You appear to have set $CFLAGS, perhaps you also need to tell GMP the
intended ABI, see "ABI and ISA" in the manual.
configure: error: Failed to configure the GMP library.

$ls -l /usr/local/lib/libgmp*
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  790194  9 11 14:04 /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     907  9 11 14:04 /usr/local/lib/libgmp.la*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      12  9 11 14:04 /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so@ -> libgmp.so.10
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  434419  9 11 14:04 /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10*
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   29292  9 11 14:04 /usr/local/lib/libgmpxx.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     943  9 11 14:04 /usr/local/lib/libgmpxx.la*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      13  9 11 14:04 /usr/local/lib/libgmpxx.so@ -> libgmpxx.so
```

.6
    -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   21092  9 11 14:04 /usr/local/lib/libgmpxx.so.6*

Regards !

Comment: There is not enough information in your report. You obviously have GMP installed, but ECL did not detect it. There must have been lines above and lines in config.log explaining why ECL failed to link GMP during the configuration phase. Could you post it?

Comment: find . -name 'config.log'
./build/config.log
./build/gmp/config.log   it is too long and how to post it ?

Comment: We need build/config.log Best thing is that you upload this as a support request here http://sourceforge.net/p/ecls/support-requests/ This is the most recommended way to do things. Alternatively send me a private email. My developer name is jjgarcia and the email address is rooted at users.sourceforge.net ;-)

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/ecls/support-requests/19/